# QCachegrind is not displaying any data for php profiling, Configuration issue may be

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, kcachegrind, qcachegrind

I have installed the xdebug , and qCachegrind, which is the windows ver of KCachegrind.. but could not see any profiling data on this interface.

May be i am unable to configure it correctly.

Let me tell you that , i have installed Xdebug already , and i am viewing it on webgrind.

Here i am posting the ini settings for xdebug:

```
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
debug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Some body please help me out here , who has used it before, couldnt find much help on internet.

Comment: Where is `xdebug.auto_trace=ON` for trace / `xdebug.profiler_enable=ON` for grind     or what starts the trace/grind?

Comment: Forgett my last.... Maybe you have to load the file into  KCachegrind manuell from C:\xampp\tmp. Did the `cachegrind.out.` exists?

Comment: yes, the file exists in this format : cachegrind.out.1468851009-C__xampp_htdocs_test_regex_validate_macaddress_php

Comment: try `https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/` on windows